# Error in UseMethod("html_table") : no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing" >

Tags: r

Code looks like this:

library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

plik_html = read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_vehicles_per_capita")
    tabela_html = html_node(plik_html, "#mw-content-text > div > table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter")

```
tabela_r = html_table(tabela_html, fill = TRUE)
```

and I get this error

```
Error in UseMethod("html_table") :    no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing" >
```

and I don't know how to fix this. Please help. I'm trying to read first table from website.

Comment: Please also specify which packages you're using. Examine individual objects and see if they're not NA by some chance...

Comment: oh there are empty rows in the table.. maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I think it's a pretty safe bet that that's the reason for `xml_missing` class. :)